# Social Authentication in Ionic App using ngCordova-oauth

Tags: android, cordova, oauth, ionic-framework

I am using ngCordova-oauth for sign up with facebook and google. App is working fine but it always use `inAppBrowser` to open webview and login. It does not detect if the user has already login in device.

how can it be achieved in ionic/cordova app that if user has already login in fb or google then take token from there rather then open webview everytime and signing up?

Answer (score 2):

How I do this as follows

1 - Let the user login for the first time via `ngCordova-oauth`

2 - Get the `authentication token` and save it, Im using [$localStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

3 - When the user opens the app for next time, I send the `authentication token` to the server and validate it (before the step 1)

4 - If the `authentication token` is valid, skip the login and move on

5 - If the user `logs out`, I clear the `authentication token`, which will invalidate the step 3, and force to log again

Comment: Thank you for your response but that token is valid on for 3600. If user login after ~10 hours then he/she has to login again.

Comment: Token expiration is a good thing.  It protects your users.  If you want longer, you need to use explicit grants via a personal web server to get refresh tokens.  It is not a good idea to request refresh tokens directly in a client facing application such as Ionic.

Comment: @NicRaboy, good point and I agree, One more step I'm doing between the step 2 and 3. I sends the user authentication to my servers and issues a different token for communication there after. Which prevents sending the users actual token back and forth. (didnt include it in the answer as thought its not relevant to the question) :)

Comment: @NicRaboy is setting a long expiry on the access token acceptable? If not, then how is anyone suppose to build cordova apps (ionic) that uses oauth2 implicit in a way that doesn't require relogging in all the time? What is the alternative? Thanks.

Comment: If you want longer than an hour you have to build a backend server and use explicit grants.  Let the server use the refresh token and return any api data rather than requesting via the front-end app.  Convenient no, good for your users yes.

Comment: @sameera207 Can you describe the step 3 with more detail or maybe an example